# Conditional Operator in Java where I don't want the false Boolean to do anything

Tags: java

I am a extremely beginner programming student working with Java.

For a section of an assignment I have a **for** loop that looks for a specific character in a string, and if it finds that character, it needs to update my count for a later section of the code. For this particular assignment, we are required to only use the **conditional (ternary) operator**. I have been able to complete the code using an ***if*** statement, but like I said, I need to use a conditional operator.

Is there a way for the false statement from a conditional operator to do nothing? Or should I have it update some garbage variable that doesn't matter instead?

**This works**

```
if (someString.charAt(i) == someChar) {
    someInt++;
}
```

**But trying to get this working**

```
someString.charAt(i) == someChar ? someInt++ : (this right here);
```

Comment: Please show your code (even if you can't complete all of it just yet).  Without code to clarify English descriptions are hard to decipher.

Comment: Pleases also add the `if` statement that you think is working.  The rest of the code would be useful too.

Comment: The way to do this is: `count += (condition) ? 1 : 0`

Comment: Yeah, for this problem it that looks like it'll work.  It's pretty unidomatic though, I wouldn't write real code that way.  Not a great problem selected by teacher.

Comment: That does it! Got it working, this one section was holding up my entire program and I just wanted to use the simple if statement... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this can help?

```
    public int answer(String input, char match) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (final char character : input.toCharArray()) {
            counter += character == match ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: Yup, that does it! Thanks!

Comment: If you think it was helpful, please up vote, hopefully this snippet can help others with similar question.

Comment: I did, but I don't have enough reputation for it to appear publicly.

Comment: No problem. Good day!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int count(String str, char ch) {
    return str.isEmpty() ? 0 : (str.charAt(0) == ch ? 1 : 0) + count(str.substring(1), ch);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP was asking.